# use sharedObject to track number of clicks

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I use sharedObject to track the number of clicks and store them in a .txt file? My client wants to track the clicks of the user an Im not sure how to make this work with sharedObject. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

If you store the clicks in SharedObject the click data will stay on the client. You'll still need to post the data to a server capture it. What you would need to store in SharedObject is a user id so you can identify which clicks belong to which user.

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("mydomain.com"); 
so.data.userId = "unique-id" // this would be a unique id from the server
so.flush(); // this writes the data in the SharedObject
```

Comment: Ok so bare with me, I am new to the sharedObject. What is ("mydomain.com") referencing and how is this script in relation to capturing the clicks and adding them to local text file?

Comment: You could have multiple SharedObjects so "mydomain.com" marks it as the shared object for that site. It doesn't have to be a domain name you can call it anything you like :)

Comment: To use the SharedObject above in counting clicks you would get the unique user id above and then post the user id (and maybe info about what the user clicked on) to the server side script. Here's and example of posting data in AS3 http://snipplr.com/view/4487/

BTW if your site uses Omniture or another another analytics suite they often have a AS3 library to make it easier to track things in AS3.

Comment: Will this work for .exe file because this is a kiosk development?